# Texture added to gameobject isn't clear

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have added a png image to a plane which is a child of my player. The texture is added as Unlit/Transparent.

The problem I am having is that at an exact orientation, my texture appears crystal clear, but at all other orientations, it blurs a tiny bit.

Since it is hard to describe in words, I recorded a short 10sec video and have it here. Please have a look for better understanding.

http://youtu.be/Z-JxYnn2ppA

There are no light sources in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the texture, be sure to check its import settings (in the *Project* window, look for your texture). The artifacts most likely have to do with the filter mode set, which my guess is bilinear filtering. Take a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Textures.html).